Use different schema registries for Kafka consumer and producer?
I have a use case where I need to consume a topic with scheam registry A. And then produce a new message on a different topic with Schema registry B.
Is there a way to use 2 schema registries with Kafka?

Yes. You'd set up two registry servers with the same bootstrap-servers and unique group ids and schema topics
Then you'd make two clients with unique schema registry URLs
This is exactly what I documented here - https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-tutorial-transfer-avro-schemas-across-schema-registry-clusters/
